# Eclipse on OS X El Capitan: Version 1.6 of the JVM is not suitable for this product

Tags: macos, java, eclipse, osx-el-capitan

I've updated to El Capitan, and now want to run Eclipse. Luna didn't work, so I downloaded the latest version, Eclipse Mars. At startup [it told me](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572) to install Java 1.6. So I did, and then I get this:

```
Version 1.6_0_65 of the JVM is not suitable for this product
Version: 1.7 or greater is required.
```

So I downloaded Java 8 for the Mac, installed that, but still get this warning.

The terminal says I'm using 1.6:

```
java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-468-11M4833)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-468, mixed mode)
```

In the System Preferences I find a Java option, which shows I have 8 installed, and it doesn't say anything about 1.6.

**How can I remove Java 1.6 from my system and use 8 as default?**

Answer (score 6):

Updating the Java version though the Java control panel updates the default system JVM, but the Eclipse installation does not appear to recognize this.

Downloading and installing the current Java Development Kit (JDK) did enable Eclipse to install successfully. For me, this resulted in the following Folder being created:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk
```

The JDK [download site is here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

BTW, There is no need to delete the previous JDK folder. Some older software might even require it.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the 1.6 version from `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`.

You’ll need root privileges to do so:

```
sudo rm -r /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.*.jdk
```

Next reinstall Eclipse and it would detect your Java 1.8 version.

Comment: Eclipse is not installed like in Windows or Linux. It's just an app that is copied to the applications folder. I've removed Java 1.6, but then I get the message that I need to install the legacy Java SE 6 runtime.

Comment: This sounds a bit hackish. Just deleting the folder will probably leave a lot of metainformation and configuration spread around the system.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Java on Mac:

```
sudo rm -fr /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin
sudo rm -fr /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefpane

cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
ls (to see what you have)
sudo rm -rf jdk1.8.0_25.jdk (or whatever version)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rename directory:

```
cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
sudo mv 1.6.0.jdk 1.6.0.jdk.old
```

Then, install eclipse and when installation was finished you can restore directory name:

`sudo mv 1.6.0.jdk.old 1.6.0.jdk`